# SWXMLHash iterating Error

Tags: xml, xcode, swift, alamofire, swxmlhash

I am new to Swift, writing my first application with network requests. For testing purposes, I created an application with the frameworks Alamofire and SWXMLHash for parsing the xml-data from the request.

In general, it works fine (more or less, I don't know how to use a completionHandler for Alamofire and I don't even understand what that really is... *shame on me*)

But now it's the first time that my xml-Structure has multiple Items of the same name and I want to iterate all of them to an Array using their "Name" attribute.

Let me give you an example for the XML:

```
<Root>
  <Results>
   <Url Name="Test1"></Url>
   <Url Name="Test2"></Url>
   <Url Name="Test3"></Url>
  </Results>
</Root>
```

So my Array should be like this:

```
["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
```

my code for this so far is not working... I get an error that unwrapping the xml data returns nil. Here is the Code of the whole file:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SWXMLHash

public var url = "http://www.testurl.com"
public var user = "testuser"

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

 @IBAction func selectedAccountActivate() {
        campaignLister()
    }

    func campaignLister(){
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["function":"catalog", "user":user, "pwd":"1234"])
            .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                //print(response)
                let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)

                var xml2: [String] = []

                for elem in xml["Root"]["Results"] {
```

/*The following line gives me the error. It works when I make a request where I only have one "URL" element, but as soon as I have many like in this example, my app crashes*/

xml2.append(elem["Url"].element!.attributes["Name"]!)
                    }
                    print(xml2)
        }
        }

```
    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me out? I used Google a lot for this problem, but I didn't find any solutions for this. Especially because I am really new to Swift...

Best regards,

hallleron

(Sorry for grammar mistakes you may find, english is not my native language.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want to do is to loop over the Url elements, like so:

```
for elem in xml["Root"]["Results"]["Url"].all {
    let urlValue = elem.element!.attributes["Name"]!;
}
```

You were looping the results element instead, but it sounds like there will always be one of those.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my issue that I'm having with SWXMLHash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236190/how-to-use-more-efficiently-swxmlhash-and-how-to-set-the-class-that-will-receive?noredirect=1#comment58257438_35236190